# Nesting resources & the creation of the inner resource by a User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to, nested-resources

Say I have a `Category` model/controller, and a `TestFile` model/controller.

Category.rb:

`has_many testfiles`

TestFile.rb:

`belongs_to category`

I've also nested the resources like so:

```
resources :categories do
    resources :testfiles
end
```

I want Users to be able to create TestFiles. In the form for creation, I want them to be able to specify a category that the test will go under.

However, the route to create a new testfile that is generated with the nesting of resources is:

`new_category_test_file_path`

which requires a `category_id` attribute to call.

How do I, in a sense, delay the setting of the category until the creation of the testfile? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you also just have a `:testfiles` resource?

Comment: You mean instead of nesting them, just have `:categories` and `:testfiles` listed as two separate resources?

Comment: No, I mean have both.